# Android: NPE in animations within fragments

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a FragmentActivity, and within the fragment I want to animate transitions between 2 views (basically 2 linearlayout, only one visible at a time).

```
public void showError() {
    if (getActivity() == null) return;
    if (mErrorView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) return;
    if (mListView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mListView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
    }
    if (mSpinnerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mSpinnerView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
    }
    mErrorView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));

    mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mErrorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mSpinnerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

It works fine, but I'm getting a lot of crash reports from users with a NPE on getActivity(). So even if I'm checking for non-null before entering, I get into a state where it becomes null (maybe because the animation is asynchronous?).

I feel like I'm not doing the animation right, is there a better way to do it and prevent all the NPE plaguing my users?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how getActivity is becoming null, but to avoid it, why not store the value before the null check.  That way you maintain a reference to it that can't become null.  Something like:

```
public void showError() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity == null) return;
//Other Code
    mErrorView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, android.R.anim.fade_in));
//Rest of code
}
```

Comment: I will try that, but somehow I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is becoming null.  Are you running that code on another thread?  Also, could you post a backtrace from the exception?